# bool to data frame pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

i have this code in the end i would like to get data frame
but i get bool type

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'dad':[1, 2, 3, 4,5, "T1", "T2"],
      'children':["T1","T1","T2","T2",6,"T3","T3"],
                 "numb":[4,5,6,9,6,7,2]})

children_list=["T1","T2",6]

filter_i=df[df["children"].isin(children_list)]["numb"]>6

print(filter_i)
```

i want that after the filter ,"filter_i" will be a data frame

Comment: Do you want `filter_i=df[df["children"].isin(children_list) & df["numb"].gt(6)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want chain both conditions, here is used `&` for bitwise `AND` and then filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
filter_i=df[df["children"].isin(children_list) & (df["numb"]>6)]
```

Or:

```
filter_i=df[df["children"].isin(children_list) & df["numb"].gt(6)]
```

Comment: It answers my need.
Thank you!